# Datagridview can't parse some symbols

Tags: c#, datagridview, symbols

I am using a dataGridView1 and it can't put correct data as :

```
=<3
```

and changed it

```
=&lt;3
```

what should do i do ?
i put data from webbrowser1 like it :

> string htmlCode = "";
>
> ```
> HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
> htmlCode = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
> doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
> dataGridView1.DataSource = "";
> dt = new DataTable();
> dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
> dt.Columns.Add("Rank", typeof(string));
> int count = 0;
> foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[not(@id='menutable')]"))
> {
>     foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
>     {
>         {
>             DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
>
>             foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("td"))
>             {
>                 if ((count % 2 == 0))
>                 {
>                     if (cell.InnerText != "Name")
>                     {
>                         dr["Name"] = cell.InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
>                     }
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     if (cell.InnerText != "Title")
>                     {
>                         dr["Rank"] = cell.InnerText.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
>                         dt.Rows.Add(dr);
>                     }
>                 }
>                 if (cell.InnerText != "Name" | cell.InnerText != "Title")
>                     count++;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
> }
> ```

Please Help me , tnx

Comment: How is this data being "put"? (The problem is something is forgetting to apply HTML escaping; that's all.)

Comment: I put data from a webBrowser1 and data it's true at there .

Comment: Show the code. How are you getting data from the `WebBrowser` control, and how are you assigning that to the `DataGridView`?

Comment: My Question is Updated Now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are outside a web application:

```
string decoded = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlEncoded);
```

In your case

```
dr["ColumnName"]=System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(cell.InnerText);
```

you can forget about `String.Replace` completely.

Comment: how can i use it ? can you tell me an example .

Comment: It's for .Net 4 and i don't want using .Net 4 , not any way ?

Comment: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode (same signature) since .Net 1.1 yet you have to include System.Web.